# Is there a way I can use Action Replay Powersaves on Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, linux, hardware, ubuntu

I'd like to use [Action Replay Powersaves](https://powersaves3ds.maximummemory.com/), but my computer is running Ubuntu and the official website has only downloads for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you won't get far with it.

**You may want to use [`wine`](https://www.winehq.org/), which will emulate a Microsoft operating system and start the Action Replay software in it.**

You will have to look up for a tutorial how to create an environment for your desired deeds. But `wine` is really easy to go with.

Though I have one of these Action Replays myself here, I unfortunatelly don't have enough time to test it myself. Never used it though. Why have I even bought it?